# Gestures using MVVM light toolkit

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, swipe-gesture

I am using the MVVM light toolkit in a WP7 application and I am trying to wire up a canvas element's appropriate event to my view model using the 'EventToCommand' behavior. The event I am looking to intercept is the 'swipe up' gesture.

I have currently tried relaying the 'KeyUp' event but that doesn't behave like I had assumed it would. Is this even possible using behaviors or should I be doing something else? All the events I wire up to the viewmodel using the EventToCommand behavior work fine, but my basic problem is that I can't find an event for a swipe. I'm guessing gestures are handled differently?

Comment: There are many web sites with info on WP7 gestures.  Try this one http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-GestureService-in-depth--key-concepts-and-API

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a way to enable a gesture to trigger the behaviour.

Fortunately, [Kevin Marshal wrote just such a thing and blogged about it](http://blogs.claritycon.com/windowsphone7/2010/07/19/wp7-gesture-recognizer-and-behavior-triggers/).